# Can someone tell me which are the advantages of using Zend Frameworks instead of simple PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Can someone tell me which are the advantages of using Zend Frameworks instead of simple PHP?
I know that it has the advantage of MVC pattern, that is OOP, it offers simplicity and enhanced security, but I would need some examples as well. Also you're welcome to list other advantages as well.

Comment: take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773/zend-php-framework

Comment: Related: [Why is Zend Framework so popular?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1833145)

Answer (score 10):

This question would be answered by it's self if you tried a framework but in a nutshell it's the same reasons people use things like jQuery for js.

Write less do more.

If you think about what a web application needs, every application needs a db class some helpers and a way to control data and views.

Frameworks provide this base layer so you don't have to spend a week researching and writing a class that will sanitize user input or rollback db transactions if they fail.

Frameworks provide the base layer of an application so you can spend more time writing the cool stuff you dream up instead of writing the boring stuff that has been done 100 times before